# css styling of unordered list containing 5 ul's with same classnames, apply different styles to each

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<li class="submenu"><a href="#">mysite</a>
<ul class="level2">(apply different style to this one)
<li><a href="#">toys</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cars</a></li>
<li><a href="#">trucks</a></li>
<li><a href="#">wagons</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="submenu"><a href="#">cooks</a>
<ul class="level2">
<li><a href="#">toys3a</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cars4b</a></li>
<li><a href="#">trucks34d</a></li>
<li><a href="#">wagonsse</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="submenu"><a href="#">campers</a>
<ul class="level2">(apply different style to this one)
<li><a href="#">toyssx</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cars12e</a></li>
<li><a href="#">trucks234s</a></li>
<li><a href="#">wagonssxzq</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

The unordered list above is generated by a category generator(php script) and  results in a drop down menu,the class names can't be changed and I would like to
apply different styles to the ul's using css, at the present my style is applied to all.Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What pattern of `ul.level2`s do you want to apply styles to?

Comment: Why can't you edit the PHP script?

Comment: I would like to write my own script but php is over my head I am studying it now and this script uses a mysql query to find the info for the script and also uses 2 functions.

Comment: I sorry but I don't understand about pattern,the ul.level2 is the dropdown part of the menu url www.cedlabs.com/chas/cart5

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`:nth-child`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild). For example, to apply CSS to the third `.level2`:

```
.submenu:nth-child(3) .level2 {
    color: red
}
```

`:nth-child` works in IE9+ and all modern browsers.  If you need it to work in, for example, older versions of IE, then you'll have to use JavaScript/jQuery and/or [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,I found this on the internet and tried it but after seeing your example I see where I made my mistakes. I used ul.level2:nth-child(3) as the example on the net was X:nth-child().I like this as it is clean and simple.

Comment: The nth-child() does not work in Firefox, could be cockpit error as I entered exactly as example and then tried #menu.submenu:nth-child(3) .level2 {     color: red } as of now no luck,thanks will keep trying

Comment: I am using firebug to make changes in html and css

Comment: It works with what you've provided: http://jsfiddle.net/uL8rF/. I can't tell you what's going wrong on your page without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem is how to select elements on your CSS stylesheet without changing the class names. You could do so by either using multiple class names or using ids.

Multiple class names are supported almost by all browsers; even IE6 although with some caveats (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Example:

```
...
<ul class="level2 custom-style-1">(apply different style to this one)
    <li><a href="#">toys</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">cars</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">trucks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">wagons</a></li>
</ul>

<li class="submenu"><a href="#">cooks</a>
<ul class="level2 custom-style-2">
...
```

Or you could just use ids

```
...
<ul id="custom-style-1" class="level2">(apply different style to this one)
    <li><a href="#">toys</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">cars</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">trucks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">wagons</a></li>
</ul>

<li class="submenu"><a href="#">cooks</a>
<ul id="custom-style-2" class="level2">
...
```

Comment: I have tried this but I admit I didn't understand it very well, now that I can see an example I will go back and edit my stylesheet and get back to you.Thanks for the example code, an eye opener.

Comment: The html for this menu is generated by a php script but I can hard code the menu as I like but lose the advantage that the categories are auto updated when added otherwise must manual enter them,briefly I have no access to the html to change or add other class names